# Font encoding in Terminal

Tags: terminal, character-encoding

I have a problem with my font encoding in terminator
When I first lauch it and then launch vim nerdTree the small ▸ are displayed well.
But if I quit vim and then type reset in my terminator they are no more displayed well.(���)

In gnome terminal they are never displayed well.

It is very annoying.
How can I fix this ?
I've tried setting encoding = UTF-8 in terminator config file.

Comment: Are you running your *terminal* as UTF-8?

Comment: @Ignacio I'm not sure what you mean with the italics, but [`terminator`](https://launchpad.net/terminator/) is a terminal emulator on its own (it's not a spelling mistake).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First make sure that the OS you are running is configured to support UTF-8. In my opinion they should all support UTF-8 by default, but some don't. Without knowing which distribution you are using it's difficult to give a detailed answer.

On Ubuntu you would edit the file `/etc/default/locale` and make sure that `LANG="en_US.UTF-8"` is in there (if you use a different language then `en_US` can be something else, but `UTF-8` must be there). If it is not, change/add it and run `locale-gen`, then restart the terminal emulator and you are done.

Comment: I'm running ArchLinux and the output of the locale cmd:
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure that your terminal encoding is set to use UTF-8, you can run the following command:

```
locale charmap  # UTF-8
```